# Is it possible to create a node-link diagram with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tree, visualization

I have a collection of data that I'm trying to visualize using something like a node-link diagram (circle or flat) or a tree diagram. The data set is [here](https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir/blob/main/Working.xlsx). There are 10 columns of data, five each for the source node and the target node. I was hoping to use some of those columns as part of the visualization; specifically the "Number" column would be used to label the data; the "Series" column would be used to color the node point; the "Level" column (ordered factor) would be used as the node shape; the "Supplement" column would be used as the link line style (solid v dashed); and the DNA column is a yes/no column where I could turn some of the points on/off in the graphic.

In the end, I think I would get something like this: [image], but with several top-level nodes of different colors/shapes.

I just can't find a place to start within ggplot (which I think is the most obvious place to start given the aesthetics variables). Is there a way to do this?

Example Data (as csv without column names) the columns are the number, series, level, supplement, and DNA for the source and the same five columns for the target.

101,91,P,No,Yes,1,91,F,No,No
101,91,P,No,Yes,09,6055,D,No,TBD
101,91,P,No,Yes,202,91,M,No,TBD
101,91,P,No,Yes,208,91,M,No,Yes
101,91,P,No,Yes,221,91,K,No,No
101,91,P,No,Yes,2,91,F,No,No
101,91,P,No,Yes,101,91,L,No,No
101,91,P,No,Yes,101,91,L,Yes,No
101,91,P,No,Yes,204,91,L,No,TBD
101,91,P,No,Yes,201,91,K,No,No
203,21,O,No,Yes,203,21,K,No,No
203,21,O,No,Yes,108,31,K,No,No
203,21,O,No,Yes,41,5210,D,No,No
203,21,O,No,Yes,100-3150,11N,R,No,Yes
101,63,N,No,Yes,1,38,F,No,No
101,63,N,No,Yes,5,13,F,No,No
101,63,N,No,Yes,01,16,X,No,TBD
2607,10,M,No,Yes,26,10,F,No,Yes
2607,10,M,No,Yes,09,3150,C,No,Yes
2607,10,M,No,Yes,9,10,F,No,Yes
2607,10,M,No,Yes,601,10,M,No,No
2607,10,M,No,Yes,101,63,M,No,No
2607,10,M,No,Yes,101,20,M,No,No
2607,10,M,No,Yes,103,99,M,No,TBD
2607,10,M,No,Yes,02,5000,C,No,Yes
2607,10,M,No,Yes,01B,6810,V,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,5,13,F,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,8040,10 USC,A,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,179,10 USC,A,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,42,5210,D,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,526,13,K,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,111,14,M,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,02,3150,D,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,102,91,M,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,101,91,M,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,41,5210,D,No,No
500,13,M,No,No,42,5210,D,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,501,13,K,No,Yes
500,13,M,No,No,117,31,M,No,Yes

Comment: This may be a good place to start: https://r-graph-gallery.com/dendrogram.html

Comment: While I like this idea, I can't seem to see how this works. The example code is so generic, I don't see how my data fits into that structure.

Comment: You may want to try the igraph package.

Comment: Can you please include some sample data as code within your question? I don't like downloading random links on the internet. It also helps avoid link rot if someone wants to benefit from your question in the future.

Comment: @Dave2e, my issue with igraph is that I can't see enough in the examples to apply them to my data.

Comment: @JonSpring - I've added a few rows of data into the post.